# Replace text between Keywords

Tags: php, replace

I want to replace all image contained in a string, which is like:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,IMAGE DATA
```

with a reference to a cid. 
Since the images can't get the same cid's, i need to replace them with an increment. But i don't know how to. Only thing i've found so far is following code, which replaces the string with the same:

```
$string = 'normal text [everythingheregone] after text ';
$pattern = '\[.*?]';
$replacement = '[test]'
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
//normal text [test] after text
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Shame on me, i should've searched a little bit more:
Here is what i've found out on replacing with increment:

```
$count = 0;
preg_replace_callback('/test/', 'rep_count', $content);

function rep_count($matches) {
global $count;
return 'test' . $count++;
}
```